# How do I check the MD5 for a file I downloaded on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: file

How would I be able to verify the MD5 for a file that I downloaded on RPi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the terminal type `openssl md5 yourfilehere`.

Answer (score 4):

openssl output is incompatible with almost everything else and impossible to use to check anything except maybe a single file. the standard way to generate MD5 checksum is to use:

```
$ md5sum file1 file2 file3 sommorefilez* >files.md5
```

the result is saved to the file using the output redirect with `>` sign and you may check the checksums later using:

```
$ md5sum -c files.md5
```

and just in case you'd prefer SHA checksums there are `sha1sum`, `sha256sum` and so on...